# Is it possible to restrict how many Cores a .Net application uses?

Tags: .net, multithreading

A problem has been discovered in a deployed .Net application on a system I have little access to, that hasn't occurred in testing. I have a fear it might be a multithreading issue.

Is there a way I can restrict the number of cores a C#.Net application can use, to effectively force it to run single-core for testing (or even as a temporary workaround while a fix is investigated)?

Comment: You can try to restrict a number of thread pool threads using [`SetMaxThreads`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.setmaxthreads?view=netcore-3.1) method

Answer (score 0):

```
start /affinity 1 test.exe
```

so it runs your app "test.exe" only on the first CPU. "1" is the [mask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc778499(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN), no matter what your code does with the thread pool.